# App Center opens as a blank screen in 23.10

Tags: 23.10, app-center

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 23.10 three times, but I cannot get the App Center to open. App Store opens as a blank white screen. I have booted in safe mode and run the fix packages program. After rebooting, the App Center opens as normal. Everything works, but after shutting down the next time I power up I get the same problem.

How can I make this fix persistent without needing to boot into safe mode every time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, for the lack of detail. App Store opens as a blank white screen. I have booted in safe mode and run the fix packages program. After re-booting the App Centre opens as normal. Everything works, but after shutting down the next time I power up I get the same problem. Does anyone have a solution to this problem. I would appreciate any help given.

Comment: To guiverc, I wasn't aware I was griping. Merely  asking for help!

Comment: @guiverc I don't see any griping here. At worst, I can detect a mild annoyance in the (now removed) suggestion that the OP might have been better off staying with a previous version, which i understandable.

Comment: @karell using killall snap-store gets the answer no process found.

Comment: @karel I would be interested in your second solution if you could share it. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing this, too. When I log into a Wayland ("Ubuntu") session from the login screen, snap-store gives me a blank screen. When I log into an Xorg session ("Ubuntu on Xorg") running snap-store works just fine. Try selecting the "Xorg" option on 23.10 and see if you can run snap-store, then?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 23.10 and later the App Center app is a snap package that is called *snap-store*. You can reload the list of available software in the App Center by closing the app and then pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and running the following commands:

```
killall snap-store
snap-store # reopen the App Center
```

This usually solves the problem. If it still doesn't work try reinstalling the App Center app.

````
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge snap-store```
sudo apt install snap-store
````

Comment: I didn't have the *snap-store* installed on my now *noble* system, but it was added only for [new installs](https://releases.ubuntu.com/23.10.1/ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.manifest) of 23.10 (this system was installed during *alpha*). When installed on this system, I had exactly what the *OP* Barry reported as occurring..  For me these instructions worked perfectly (*thus my upvote*).  I fear however the issue maybe related to server issues on Canonical infrastructure (I'm getting a lot of 50x errors with `rmadison` etc)  thus the re-occurrence & there maybe no fix for that except patience?

Comment: this did not solve the same issue i had too

Comment: I tried doing the steps answered by karel and unfortunately snap-store does not exist anymore on a clean install. Unable to locate package.

Comment: @Sugar In Ubuntu 23.10 and later the App Center app is a snap package that is called snap-store. App Center is installed by default in Ubuntu 23.10 and later. To install it run `sudo snap install snap-store`

Comment: I am having this issue, too, where opening the App Center is only showing a blank window. Running "sudo snap remove snap-store" and "sudo snap install snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10" did not help; the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

When I run with a discrete video card it opens.

Right-click the mouse and choose "Launch using discrete Graphics Card"

Comment: Right-click the mouse and choose " Launch using discrete Graphics Card"