# The New App center and Firmware updater From Ubuntu 23.10 is displaying blank white screen and not loading

Tags: updates, software-center, 23.10, app-center

I recently dual booted the new Ubuntu 23.10 and played around a little bit, everything seems to work fine for me but When I try to open the app center (snap-center) and Firmware updater, neither of them seems to work at all and just displays a blank white screen and I tried doing every fix available out there from trying to reinstall it to update it to latest packages and even installing gnome software center but nothing helped at all any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App centre in 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490737/app-centre-in-23-10)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble... I hope someone will answer your question soon.
Till then, I installed the previous version with the following command.

sudo apt install gnome-software

At least I can find software there till they fix the problem.