# App Center just showing up as a blank screen (im on a raspberry pi 400)

Tags: software-center, raspberrypi

App Center just showing up as a blank screen (im on a raspberry pi 400)

When accessing the software center, if it appears blank

Comment: the reson why i tagged that is cuz u have to tag 5 things so i tagged that (im using the latest verson of unbuntu LTS)

Comment: also im using the unbuntu app center

Comment: when posting my queston it said i had to tag atleast 5 thing idk why

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Also, the name is Ubuntu, not 'unbuntu'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App Center opens as a blank screen in 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490737/app-center-opens-as-a-blank-screen-in-23-10)